# Windows Phone 8 and Microsoft Expression Blend 4

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, blend

I want to program a mockup of a Windows Phone application. I installed the WP8 SDK but the software Microsoft Expression Blend 4 doesn't show me Windows Phone. Do you have any idea how can I could solve this problem?

Comment: are you using Blend for visual studio 2012? That seems to have windows phone 8 support.

Also, can you create a windows phone 8 project in Visual Studio? (to verify that the SDK was installed correctly)

Comment: Yes, I can create a windows phone 8 project in Visual Studio 2012. I have already used Blend for Visual Studio but to make a mockup, it's better to use Expression Blend 4, isn't it?

Comment: Expression suite of software was discontinued.  If you want to create a Windows Phone 8 application you need to use Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression blend 4 generally had support for windows phone 7. With WP8 microsoft shifted to Blend for visual studio. See this link [ANNOUNCING WINDOWS PHONE 8 SDK](http://blendinsider.com/news/announcing-windows-phone-8-sdk-design-great-apps-with-blend-2012-10-30/)